# Transformar string (data e hora)

Tags: mysql, asp

É um sitemap xml (google news) e tenho que fazer sair assim:

```
<news:publication_date>2019-02-19T18:57:26-03:00</news:publication_date>
```

Meus campos estão com o seguinte formato, ambos strings:

data= 19/02/2019
hora= 18:38:25

Poder ser em MYSQL ou ASP Classic.

Comment: Você deseja concatenar os campos ? `concat` não lhe serve ? Adicione na pergunta o que você já tentou para este problema.

Comment: Concatenar é o de menos, como transformar data e hora, estão em campos separados, em string, e exibidos em padrão brasileiro para campos em padrão americano, como está na pergunta.

Comment: string data = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-02-19T19:18:20-03:00").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") - Tente isso após fazer um concat nos campos. Não resolveria seu problema?

Comment: é asp 3. asp classic

Comment: @LeonardoL atualizei a pergunta, acho que agora ficou mais claro.

Comment: ASP Classic é sem .NET? Contando apenas com os objetos VBScript?

Comment: sim. asp 3 ovelho asp vab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse [link](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_vbscript_functions.asp#date) você vai encontra as funções VBScript para manipulação de tempo e datas no ASP Classic.

Para resolver seu problema primeiro você vai pegar a data e hora atual do sistema e colocar em uma variável `data` e outra `time`.

```
<%
  Rem essas variáveis já deve ter sido declaradas em seu código
  Rem fica apenas como parte do exemplo
  dim data
  dim hora
  data = Now
  hora = Time
%>
```

Então use as funções [`Year(data)`](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_year.asp) para extrair o ano, [`Month(data)`](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_month.asp) para extrair o mês e [`Day(data)`](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_day.asp) para extrair o dia e monte a sentença de acordo com a sua necessidade.

```
<%
  response.write("<news:publication_date>" & Year(data) & "-" & Month(data)& "-" & Day(data) & "T" & hora & "-03:00" & "</news:publication_date>")
%>
```

Comment: Faz muito tempo que não mexo com isso se tiver algum erro de sintaxe fique a vontade para editar a resposta.

Comment: opa, muito obrigado. Oque seria essa "T" e esse "-03:00" será que é um valor fixo? Será que é parâmetro de fuso horário?

Comment: @Rod: T-3:00 é fuso horário e relação a Greenwich. T vem de translation(translação) from Greenwich.

Comment: to vendo aqui que esse valor varia ás vezes para "-02:00". Não sei que padrão é esse que o google news pede.

Comment: Cada local tem um fuso diferente. Se a noticia foi veiculada em São Paulo o T-3:00. Se for veiculada aqui em Campo Grande o T-4:00.

Comment: entendi. vou concatenar as datas com esse valor fixo de -03:00 então, estamos do rio. Tem a questão do horário de verão né.

Comment: @Rod já ta ok, até tirei o comentário.